# HTTP request post from Microsoft Azure Logic Apps to PC via Azure VPN?

Tags: azure, post, http-post, azure-logic-apps

I have a problem that I cannot solve at all. I want to do a HTTP POST request from Azure to my PC (as I have a server running on my PC). The server itself cannot have a public IP address or be hosted anywhere else, it has to be on my PC.
I have created a VPN Gateway on the Azure, to which my PC normally connects.

To get the url for the POST request i use this :

```
echo {"name": "httpSource","namespace": "XXXXXXXXX","protocols": ["http"],"description": "Source for HTTP","tags": ["data", "HTTP"]} | curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "XXXXXXXXX" -d @- "XXXXXXXXX"
```

(I removed the sensitive data for security)

So i get the url as a result in the CMD, add the VPN ip but once i put it in the logic app i get this

[logic app answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53yqs.png)

So what seems to be the problem? Why is it not resolving the name? How to make this work?

Thanks in advance for any help, it's driving me crazy